# Getting the result of jquery .post() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to find out how to access "data" variable outside of the post function.  It will return either `valid` or `invalid` so I can finish the main function logic.

Is this the right way to do it:

```
$('#form_choose_methods').submit(function(){
    var voucher_code = $('#voucher_code').val();
    var check = $.post(baseURL+"ajax.php", { tool: "vouchers", action: "check_voucher", voucher_code: voucher_code },
        function(data) {
    });
    alert(check);
    return false;
});
```

`check` seems to be the object, but I want to know how to access result of it.

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133310/how-can-i-get-jquery-to-perform-a-synchronous-rather-than-asynchronous-ajax-req

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access the response in the success callback you use

```
 $.post(baseURL+"ajax.php", { tool: "vouchers", action: "check_voucher", voucher_code: voucher_code },
        function(data) {
       // you can access the response in here
       alert(data);
    });
```

Ajax calls are asynchronous, so you will only have access to the result from the callback ***whenever*** it completes..

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#form_choose_methods').submit(function () {
    var voucher_code = $('#voucher_code').val();
    $.post(baseURL + "ajax.php", { tool: "vouchers", action: "check_voucher", voucher_code: voucher_code },
        function (data) {
            if (data == "valid") {
                //do seomthing
            }
            else {
                //do something else
            }
        });
});
```